# JMeter - how to stimulate parallel requests

Tags: jmeter

I have the following setup:

[image]

I want to execute 100 requests, 10 times. And as I am using parallel controller I assume that I am executing 300 requests at the same second.

Can I assume that my threads are sending the request at the same time or there can be some delay between individual requests?

I suppose there is a delay or I am hitting some application or web limit, because when I start the test and observe the database activities, I am seeing only several requests per seconds to be handled?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can send whatever number of requests you want however the actual [throughput](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/glossary.html) (number of requests per unit of time) will depend mostly on application response time and other metrics like connect time and latency.

JMeter will have to wait for till all requests complete prior to starting the next iteration and if your application response time is above 1 second - you will not reach 300 requests per second. You can check the actual number of requests per second using i.e. [Server Hits Per Second](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/HitsPerSecond/) plugin.

Also make sure you're following [JMeter Best Practices](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html), in particular:

- [Run your test in command-line non-GUI mode](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#non_gui)
- [Remove all the listeners from your test plan](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/greedy-listeners-memory-leeches-performance-testing)

as if JMeter will fail to send requests fast enough you will never reach the desired load even if your application capacity is huge.

Comment: Thanks. I am using apache ant to execute the test. Should I remove the listeners again?